# Form Custom Radio Buttons Adding a Active Class to change background

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

Im trying to get a Active Class onto some radio buttons without the actual radio button its more just a group of buttons Ill share an image,html its generated so itll be a little messy

Css,

And then if anyone has any idea's because when I use the actual class of E.G

```
#wedo-contact .frm_radio:focus-within{
    background-color:#D81B2D!important;
}
```

it works but Active Visited doesn't

So the issue is obviously on focus it'll work but as soon as you get to the next field you'll loose focus and itll seem to the user that they lost the selection

If anyone has a JQ, or Css solution for this as I cant edit on the actual radio buttons they're generated threw a loop on a plugin

[image]

```css
.frm_radio:focus-within {

  background-color: #D81B2D!important;

}

.frm_style_formidable-style.with_frm_style .frm_radio label,
.frm_style_formidable-style.with_frm_style .frm_checkbox 
label:active {
  background-color: #D81B2D!important;
}

 .frm_radio label:active {
  background-color: #D81B2D!important;
}

 .frm_radio:hover {
  background-color: #D81B2D!important;
}

 .frm_radio label:visited {
  background-color: #D81B2D!important;
}

.frm_radio:link {
  background-color: #D81B2D!important;
}

 .frm_radio:-moz-focus-inner {
  background-color: #D81B2D!important;
  outline: none!important;
}

input[type=radio]{ 
opacity: 0!important;
width: 0px!important;
height: 0px!important;
margin: 0px!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="frm_radio" id="frm_radio_18-0">
  <label for="field_yhi3q-0">       
   <input type="radio" name="item_meta[18]" id="field_yhi3q-0" value="WEB DESIGN &amp; 
     DEVELOPMENT" data-invmsg="I would like to talk to you about is invalid"> WEB DESIGN &amp; 
       DEVELOPMENT</label>
</div>
```

Comment: I made a snippet. Please update it to make a [mcve]

Comment: Thank you@mplungjan updated the snippet

Comment: [RTM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited) visited is for links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add and remove a class when you click on it with javascript. It makes the CSS a lot simpeler as well.

I simplified the HTML a bit for demonstation purposes.

```js
// Get all radioBoxes
const radioBoxes = document.querySelectorAll(".frm_radio input[type='radio']");

// Highlight .frm_radio div
const highLightRadioBox = (radioBox) => {
  // Deselect all radioBoxes
  radioBoxes.forEach((box) => {
    getParentFrmRadio(box).classList.remove("active");
  });

  // Select current radioBox
  getParentFrmRadio(radioBox).classList.add("active");
};

// Get parent element to highlight
/*
 * radioBox.parentNode is your label
 * radioBox.parentNode.parentNode is your .frm_radio div
*/

const getParentFrmRadio = (radioBox) => radioBox.parentNode.parentNode;

// Add change event to all radioBoxes
radioBoxes.forEach((radioBox) => {
  radioBox.addEventListener("change", () => highLightRadioBox(radioBox));
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: #D81B2D !important;
  outline: none !important;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=radio]{ 
  opacity: 0 !important;
  width: 0 !important;
  height: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.frm_radio {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="frm_radio">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="name" />
    WEB DESIGN
  </label>
</div>

<div class="frm_radio">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="name" />
    SOMETHING ELSE
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Works great just a small issue its 

```<div> <label> <input> ``` The Div is the element that needs the active so i went and sayd getElementbyClassName("frm_radio") but for some reason it attaches the active class to the label and not the div and id need it to remove the previous selected if i select a new one could you possibly demonstrate that? you can have a test if you like 
http://azipit.co.za/lionremaster/wedo/
Go down to the contact us you'll see what i mean

Comment: @Someguy I changed my example. It now only changes if the item is selected. This way you can click on the label and then it will update the active state. It might be that your label doesn't cover your whole `.frm_radio` div but that can easily be changed with CSS